# How do I download a specific version of source code from android.googlesourcecode.com using Git?

Tags: download, android-source, git-clone

I want to download the source code shown in the tags from `android.googlesourcecode`.
For example, I want to download calendar code

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar

I also want to download the code of android specific version tag. For example,`android-4.0.3_r1.1` from the following link

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar/+/android-4.0.3_r1.1.

When I browse this code from git repositories it doesn't show the tag's version of code. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

All the tags are listed in the [Calendar page](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar/) under [All Tags](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar/+refs).  That page contains `android-4.0.3_r1.1`.

If you clone the repo and look for that tag, you will find it as well. For example:

```
C:\prog\git>git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar
Cloning into 'Calendar'...
remote: Counting objects: 80, done
remote: Finding sources: 100% (80/80)
remote: Total 30504 (delta 15730), reused 30504 (delta 15730)
Receiving objects: 100% (30504/30504), 11.16 MiB | 4.61 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (15730/15730), done.

C:\prog\git>cd Calendar

C:\prog\git\Calendar>git tag|grep 4.0.3
android-4.0.3_r1
android-4.0.3_r1.1
...
```

From there, a simple `git checkout android-4.0.3_r1.1` will allow you to browse the sources for that specific tag.